# There's GOLD in dem der hills!

Tags: cipher

A pirate's treasure...
Billy the pirate buried his plunder at the mouth of a large river. He killed all of his crew then made his way on foot back to civilization. He ended up getting sick with yellow fever and died in a hospital bed.

Just before he passed he whispered to the nurse the coordinates to the buried gold. The nurse believed it was the high fever and delirium, but he insisted she write it down.

Many years later her great-grandson Jack, while packing for the second Great War, found the note in a box belonging to his long dead relative. Not knowing the importance of the note, he sent a telegram over the wire to his grandfather who was still living in DC.

Unfortunately the message never reached his grandfather: the Germans had intercepted the telegram. The U-boat captain prepared to send the message back to high command, when the sub hit a mine.

My grandfather found the message during a salvage operation. Can anyone help me find the gold?

```
y7.9z/d.f4!\,j01"r@p$(5)+wzyx.7e/h,l0fom@81ou y'+v4/3-7x!\?@e,"5'+$@mnrqb+avde-zyxa9oe3,qlu o@nwz5r-zy .sd/3,2l9\?@8r0pu v(1)-7bc(4defhc!\?omh"5'+ mstd5'q$(6)o
```

It's probably an easy one to solve. I can give a hint if necessary.

Comment: "Many years later *her* great grandson Jack..."  Is the "her" a typo? or is it a part of the puzzle?

Comment: Interestingly, the `@` symbols are highly anachronistic.  It wasn't until [1971](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/the-accidental-history-of-the-symbol-18054936/?no-ist) that it really started being used on any regular basis.

Comment: @KritixiLithos "her" is in reffernrece to the nurse who wrote down the coordinates not part of the puzzle

Comment: Couldn't Jack just send the message again with another telegram over the wire, since I assume he didn't destroy the original document?

Comment: Is the story needed for solving the puzzle?

Comment: Do we need to know German seeing that this is a U-boat we are talking about here?

Comment: Thoughts: It's not a straight substitution cipher - There are 48 distinct characters, none of which shows up more than 6 times, with 3 being the most common number of occurrences. I also didn't get anything much useful in going through ASCII encoding.

Comment: We need the [bombe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombe)

Comment: If the spaces are used to separate words, the first two "words" of 45 letters line up at some irregular points. For example, the first and last letters (y, u) coincide and some of the punctuation (forward slash, exclam, backslash and dollar), too. The remaining words can be made to paritally line up with this, too, but I don't see a clear pattern here. And what's with the groups of alphabetically close letters (wzyx, defhc, mnrq)?

Comment: Maybe the word GOLD is the key to some kind of shift?

Comment: @JLee - It's probably a key of some sort, but it's definitely more than just a shift.

Comment: @Len, bscott has been gone since the day after this question was posted. Doubt if we'll get any hints.

Comment: The 'note' text looked like some sort of hashing string to me. A search on google finds [this site](http://goldparser.org/), which I think is the engine to decrypt the note hash. I am unable to find where to download the engine since many of the links don't work, so I do not believe this puzzle will ever have an answer.

Comment: @Eric A [Gold code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code) , also known as Gold sequence, is a type of binary sequence, used in telecommunication CDMA and satellite navigation GPS. In line with the question, maybe a lead ?

Comment: @Eric i'm thinking the message may be a [python or cjam](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55632/dead-code-elimination) string. Look at examples Pyth, 40 bytes and further along CJam, 49 bytes. The Gold code doesn't seem to be panning out. (see what i did there?) xD

Comment: Perhaps a binary shift based on morse code rather than an ascii conversion?

Comment: @usernamenotused , how does that work ? where would you start ?

Comment: Pls give the hint

Comment: "It's probably an easy one to solve"

Comment: Could be a historical puzzle. What encryption did the Germans use in this context? I believe there was a movie about this recently.

Comment: It's... something

Comment: So, a couple of observations - I think this is probably a puzzle that revolves around misunderstandings in the retelling of the answer (it went orally from the pirate to the nurse to the (in Europe?) grandson to a telegram to German.  Also, there may be issues with anachronisms in the retelling due to time differences.  Also, if there truly was a telegram, then some of the characters in the cipher should be "STOP".  However, no idea if the OP was clever enough to include that.

Comment: I think we can rule out computer-based encryptions (and ASCII and other such things) because of the timing. The great-great grandchild was in World War 1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The German and WWII references indicate that the message went through...

> **1. Enigma machine encryption**
>
>  This [online tool](http://www.counton.org/explorer/codebreaking/enigma-cipher.php) is the most straightforward for quickly decoding this puzzle's message. Use G, O, L, D in the "Position" boxes, enter the message in the "Encrypted Text" field, and hit the "Decrypt" button to get
>
> ```
> .-.. .- - .. - ..- -.. . ----- .-.-.- ..--- ...-- ...-- ....- ..... ----. .-.. --- -. --. .. - ..- -.. . -....- ....- ----. ..... -.... ---.. ----. ...-- ----.
> ```
>
> I'll see if I can replicate the results using another tool.

Then, the telegram reference and the look of the decoded message from the first step has the message's original encryption of...

> **2. Morse code**
>
>  Translating the result of the first decryption gets
>
> ```
> LATITUDE0.233459LONGITUDE-49568939
> ```
>
> I could've made a mistake in the decryption somewhere, but I think there's a decimal missing in the longitude? Searching the coordinates 0.233459,-49.568939 online gave me a location in or near Canal Perigoso, Brazil.

And now the story makes much more sense to me. It is not just for flavour.

Comment: And those coordinates are near the mouth of a large river, and that would be a likely place for someone to get yellow fever. Bravo.

Comment: I don't think I would've gotten this if I haven't been trying to solve another crypto puzzle and looking up Enigma Machine variations. Me = :D

Comment: Bravo! I am so pleased.

Comment: This is an amazing find!  Looking through the site's code, it uses a fixed set of nonstandard wheels (and no plugboard).  I think if you hadn't come across this exact implementation, we never would have solved it; nice detective work!

Comment: Good job @Mythi I have accepted your answer, it is correct

Answer (score 7):

I'm new here, I hope this is the right place to post, since it is more of a possible hint than an answer:

The fact that the word GOLD is emphasized in the question caught my attention, and reminded me of "[The Gold-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gold-Bug)", a short story by Edgar Allan Poe, in which the protagonists decipher a secret message to find a treasure buried by a pirate (Coincidence? I think not).

The cipher in Poe's novel is a simple substitution cipher that they crack using frequency analysis. Assuming we're faced with a simple substitution cipher here too (which would explain the "It's probably an easy one to solve" line from the author of the question), I tried to brute-force it a little but haven't got enough spare time on my hands to dig further.

(A last remark, that may or may not be of use: If the word "GOLD" is part of the clear text, it doesn't matter whether the clear is in English or in German, since it is the same word in the two languages.)

Comment: @Bobson mentioned that there are 48 distinct characters, so a simple substitution cipher seems unlikely. I *do* really like the potential connection with Poe, though. I'll think on that.

Answer (score 0):

**WIKI FOR ANALYSIS**

Character mix and frequency:

```
CHAR    ASCII   FREQ
---------------------
        32      5
!       33      3
"       34      3
$        36      3
'       39      4
(       40      4
)       41      3
+       43      5
,       44      5
-       45      4
.       46      4
/       47      4
0       48      3
1       49      3
2       50      1
3       51      3
4       52      3
5       53      5
6       54      1
7       55      4
8       56      2
9       57      3
?       63      3
@       64      6
\       92      4
a       97      2
b       98      2
c       99      2
d       100     5
e       101     5
f       102     3
h       104     3
j       106     1
l       108     3
m       109     4
n       110     2
o       111     6
p       112     2
q       113     3
r       114     4
s       115     2
t       116     1
u       117     3
v       118     3
w       119     2
x       120     3
y       121     5
z       122     5
```